# "Fernet" python encoding gives me the following error: ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

Tags: python, fernet

I have the following code that takes the encrypted keys from a .bin file

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    def C(i):
      f=open('/home/credentials.bin',"rb")
      e=f.read()
      e=e.split("\n")
      e2=e[-2]
      d = Fernet(e2)
      c = e[i]
      t = (d.decrypt(c))
      s= bytes(t).decode("utf-8")
      f.close()
      return str(s)
    
    print(C(0))
```

trying to print the decrypted key gives me the following error:

```
"Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes."
```

ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.

credentials.bin continent `

> `"gAAAAABeTAKV_odfhx3i6BhiaXeEDdxvG3eDdployKspvIcnm87zXd94fklNm1mMVkTlN6UUehyw0VzgNU1mj0Zlzi6yNynmOA=="`

`

I appreciate your help

Comment: Without `credentials.bin` difficult to say.  Make a [mcve].

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post full traceback you get. As a side note - use descriptive names, not cryptic, one-letter names.

Comment: Thanks for the observation edit the question adding the content of the bin file which contains the encrypted key

Comment: You code should error before that.  You are trying to split a bytes object with a string in     `e = e.split('\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key is too long for a Fernet key:
it is:

```
len("gAAAAABeTAKV_odfhx3i6BhiaXeEDdxvG3eDdployKspvIcnm87zXd94fklNm1mMVkTlN6UUehyw0VzgNU1mj0Zlzi6yNynmOA==")
```

output:

```
100
```

whereas fernet keys are:

```
len(Fernet.generate_key())
```

output:

```
44
```

The only way it works with your key is if you cut off the first part but I am pretty sure this is **not** how it was intended

```
Fernet("gAAAAABeTAKV_odfhx3i6BhiaXeEDdxvG3eDdployKspvIcnm87zXd94fklNm1mMVkTlN6UUehyw0VzgNU1mj0Zlzi6yNynmOA=="[-45:-1])
```

output:

```
<cryptography.fernet.Fernet object at 0x7feb65b5bf10>
```

I think you have the wrong key here, or it is not a Fernet key.